# ack not accepting shorthand character classes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, grep, ack

When I search for `\d` with ack, it brings up every match for the letter "d" rather than for digits 0-9 as the `\d` shorthand class should represent, identical to `[0-9]`.

Why might this be? I read through the man page and didn't find anything about it. I'm using the newest stable version of ack. Why doesn't it support shorthand character classes?

Comment: @glennjackman Question is asking about [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/), not awk.

Comment: bah, it's late and the kids were bouncing off the walls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably forgotten to quote or escape the search query to prevent it from being interpreted by your shell, e.g.

```
ack '\d'
```